# can't go back in iframe of wordpress website in other webiste(cross-origin frame)

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I have a wordpress website and other website and I added iframe of the wordpress website in the other.

I navigate in the iframe, then trying to go back using:

```
window.parent.frames[0].history.back()
```

but got error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "xxxxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

There is some way to solve it?
thanks